# UIRouter navigate @uirouter/angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am working on angular 4.x. How to redirect to another state from my component? I am using @uirouter/angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inject UIRouter and use the `stateService`

```typescript
@Component({...})
export class YourComponent {
    constructor(private router: UIRouter) { }

    navigateMethod() {
        this.router.stateService.go('name-of-your-state');
    }
}
```

If you want to navigate to url, then use `urlService`

```typescript
...
navigateMethodToUrl() {
    this.router.urlService.url('your-url', false);
}
...
```